# How can I set the default visibility of the main Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have run my program step by step, but still, I can't find where the `form.visible` is set.

Here is the code of "Form1.cs":

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Hide();
}
```

I added `this.Hide();` but it didn't work at all.

and I even modified "Program.cs" from:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

to:

```
Form1 form1=new Form1();
form1.Visible = false;
Application.Run(form1);
```

But the main form still showed, even adding `form1.Enable=false;` won't stop the form from showing. I have also tried adding `this.Hide();` in `Form1_Load()`, it worked but the main form appeared and flashed before it was finally hidden.

I'm totally confused now. So how can I load the main form without showing it? And keep it hidden until I call `this.Show();`?

Comment: If you need to init something before loading the form, can't you do that in Program.cs before loading the form?

Comment: You could push your logic before the Application.Run(new Form1()) statement and when you're ready, call it.

Comment: How about showing a splash screen while you do pre-load stuff? You can even show a progress bar and doesn't appear to the user as if the app is not starting.

Comment: @sventevit thank you for answering. The problem is that the "logic" I need can not be put in Program.cs. In fact, adding `Form form2=new Form();` in Form1.cs performs normally, whether the new form will show is up to the property `form2.Visible`. But calling Application.Run(form2) will show the form even if the form2.visible is set to false. I don't know why...

Comment: @jimjupiter    thank you for your answer. But in fact, I don't even know when the form should be shown, it is designed to be invisible until another thread calls `.Show()`. The wired thing is that `Application.Run()` will show the form in spite of the property `form.Visible=false`. It's really confusing..

Comment: @jimjupiter If there were an event "Form_PreLoad()", it would be helpful to me. :)

Comment: @wings What would you do in that event (supposing it existed) that you cannot do in the constructor, or in the regular Load event?

Comment: The Problem has been solved. I have learned that `Application.Run(form)` will make the form the "main form", and the "main form" will be shown anyway. So I set the property `.Opacity=0` instead of `.Visible=false`. So when the "main form" is shown, it is still invisible cause it is transparent, then I can set `.Opacity` to show the main form.:)

Comment: @hvd The thing I want to do is of course `this.Hide()`, so I want it to be done before the form is shown. If I write it into the constructor or in the regular Load event, the form will show at first, then flash and hide. I don't want to see the flashing window, I just want it be invisible at first~

Comment: @wings I misunderstood you, then, I thought the point was that you wanted to do things there before showing the form. What you've come up with will make for a horrible user experience, as a fully transparent form can still be interacted with. As I mentioned in my answer, there are other `Application.Run` overloads that don't show a main form. Why are those not an option?

Comment: The Form_Load event fires after the initialise, and that is where you need to set the `Form.Visible = false` or in the Shown event as per @irsog 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not override the SetVisibleCore method:

```
bool showForm = false;

protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
{    
   base.SetVisibleCore(showForm);
}
```

This will hide the form before it even opens up. With a lot of method's you see a brief flash of the form before its .Visible or similar property is set to "hide".

Obviously you will need another method to flip 'showForm' to true when you want to display it again i.e. NotifyIcon event.

Comment: thank you, I think your answer is the best solution to my problem. It helps a lot~

Answer (score 2):

you can not set form `visible` to `false` before load it try this code:

```
//In Main Function
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
form1.ShowInTaskbar = false;
Application.Run(new Form1());
//In Form Shown
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [Application.Run(Form)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx) clearly spells out that it will make the form visible. As long as you need to keep it hidden, you should therefore not pass that form to Application.Run. Depending on your needs, you may be able to use [Application.Run()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900) (no arguments) or [Application.Run(context)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901) (create a custom `ApplicationContext`) instead.

*Edit*: I just want to add that to not show the form, **you should not show the form**. I don't understand how so many users here think it's a good idea to show the form and then hide it really quickly, or make the code that shows the form not show the form. You shouldn't be doing the wrong thing and then fixing it after the fact, you should do the right thing in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the `Opacity` property. You can set `Opacity` to `0.0` from the IDE. It can take values between `0.0` and `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var form = new Form1();
        form.DoBeforeShow();
        Application.Run(form);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can load the form you permanently want to show to the user. In the constructor only call the form which should be hidden. Afterwards you can close or hide it.